# POD in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void is_pod(char* c)
{
    cout << "Type " << c;
    if(std::is_pod<T>::value)
        ::std::cout << " is POD" << endl;
    else
        ::std::cout << " is not!" << endl;
}

#define CHECK_TYPE(ty) ::is_pod<ty>(#ty)

struct POD_Parent{};
struct POD_Child : public POD_Parent{int y;};
struct POD_Child2 {int x; POD_Parent y; POD_Child ssd;};

int main()
{
    CHECK_TYPE(POD_Parent);
    CHECK_TYPE(POD_Child);
    CHECK_TYPE(POD_Child2);
```

Gives the following results: Which is strange!

```
Type POD_Parent is POD
Type POD_Child is not!
Type POD_Child2 is POD
```

How can POD_Child is not POD?! and POD_Child2 is POD?!!

Note that I compiled it using MinGW (using option -std=c++11) and it said that all of them are POD.

Comment: sorry i didn't see POD_Child as a member of POD_Child2, i deleted the answer as it was not correct :)

Comment: [Things have changed (quite a bit) since 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special/7189821#7189821), and the old compiler has  probably just got it wrong.

Comment: I get the same result in VC2010 as you got in 2008.

Comment: VC2012 the same result. It is a bug, obviously. So, please, file it to MS connect

Comment: It must be a bug in MSVC. More on POD types:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `[MSDN][1]` a type that has a base class is not `POD` so `POD_Child` is not `POD` but for `POD_Child2` its possibly some mistake of the compiler that ignore base class of `ssd`